# How to achieve deferred deep linking in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, deep-linking

I am familiar with deep linking, but I only have a theoretical understanding of deferred deep linking on iOS.

I am using the this tutorial:

`http://blogs.innovationm.com/deferred-deep-linking-in-ios-with-universal-link/`

but I do not get how to share the url/token between the web browser and the Mobile Application using javascript and `SFSafariViewController`. Could somebody explain how I can achieve deferred deep linking, if they has cracked it.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

### SFSafariViewController Cookie Matching

I believe you are referring to SFSafariViewController cookie matching. This is done by storing cookies in the Safari app and then pulling those cookies out of a hidden instance of an SFSafariViewController since they shared the same cookies. Unfortunately in iOS 11, Apple got rid of this cookie sharing.

### Finger Printing

To solve a deferred deep linking on your own, you can attempt to perform finger print matching. This involves some server side logic and can become unwieldy as you scale. The basic idea is to extract a set of parameters about the users device when the link is clicked on i.e. OS, screen size, OS version, IP Address and store that information in your server. When a user then opens your app, extract a similar set of parameters and make a request to your server to find the device that most closely matches the device that just opened your app. This technique will not be 100% but if done well you should be able to match with high likelihood.

### Memory-based Matching

The benefits of using [Branch](https://branch.io) (note: **I'm the author of this software**) is that you can leverage the network of matches made by other Branch apps in the past. For example, if a user uses the Airbnb app, Branch can associate their device info with their browser info and store that for use of any other Branch app. Therefore, you would be able to leverage the matches of other large apps. Branch also provides free deep linking, so it does not make sense to build this yourself.

Comment: Make sure that you disclose your association with Branch in your answers. These are being flagged as spam by members of the community.